# Cytoscape 3.8.2 doesn't start. Mac OS 10.14.6. Java SE 12.0.1

Tags: cytoscape

I can't start Cytoscape. I tried to run the ./Mac.sh script and I get these errors

./mac.sh: line 1: bplist00?_WebMainResource: command not found
./mac.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<' ./mac.sh: line 2:`

```
               _WebResourceFrameName_WebResourceData_WebResourceMIMEType_ebR(<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">#!/bin/bash'
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape 3.8 requires Java 11 and will not work, in general, with Java 12.